# How to install libncurses.so.5 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, 32-bit, ncurses

I need both 32 bit and 64 bit for `libncurses.so.5` on Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) for building an Android application on an older Android NDK. What are my options? `libncurses.so.5` is not on apt-get anymore.

Comment: The i386 binary package is available - https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libncurses5 https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libncurses5-dev or am I missing something?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/i386/libncurses5/filelist

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to update your package lists, as this package [is still](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libncurses.so.5) available from [*universe*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libncurses5) pocket.

Install them with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install libncurses5 libncurses5:i386
```

Comment: this is weird, in the Software & Updates gui, the checkbox for Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe) is checked!

Tried `grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and universe appears there.

Comment: it magically found the packages after I restarted my computer (had not restarted in at least a week...). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Thats solved my: Wine cannot find the ncurses library (libncurses.so.5)

Comment: Isn't apt update missing between add repository and install?

Answer (score 4):

So adding the `universe` pocket didn't completely solve my problem, I found out that I also had to set up the correct foreign architecture.

To set this up, I first checked main architecture, which was `amd64`, and foreign architecture was empty. So I needed to add the `i386` architecture as well.

```
$ sudo dpkg --print-architecture 
$ sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```